# In ubuntu Set Manual and PAC file both at the same time

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, pac

I have a requirement, where a ubuntu user will set the manual proxy in the system, and at the same time to drive the traffic according to my software I need to set a PAC file for specific traffic. I need to have a manual proxy as well as a PAC file proxy in the system **at the same time**. I need to set up the PAC file programmatically.
Is there a way to do so in ubuntu like it can be done in Windows and Darwin?

Comment: Which browser will be used by the end user? If they are using the same browser as on Windows, it should behave the same or very similar. E.g. Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: yea, right. that's not the issue. I want to keep both, PAC file and manual proxy config, at the same time. so that those who use PAC will use PAC and those who do not use PAC will use manual proxy settings. both Manual and PAC proxy shall point to the different proxies.